# Finding trailing 0s in a binary number

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

How to find number of trailing 0s in a binary number?Based on K&R bitcount example of finding 1s in a binary number i modified it a bit to find the trailing 0s.

```
int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
  int b;
  for(b=0;x!=0;x>>=1)
      {
        if(x&01)
          break;
        else
          b++;
      }
```

I would like to review this method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221914/number-of-trailing-zeroes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a way to compute the count in parallel for better efficiency:

```
unsigned int v;      // 32-bit word input to count zero bits on right
unsigned int c = 32; // c will be the number of zero bits on the right
v &= -signed(v);
if (v) c--;
if (v & 0x0000FFFF) c -= 16;
if (v & 0x00FF00FF) c -= 8;
if (v & 0x0F0F0F0F) c -= 4;
if (v & 0x33333333) c -= 2;
if (v & 0x55555555) c -= 1;
```

Comment: How does it work? It's hard to understand how it was derived.

Comment: It's a bisection / binary search on bit level.

Comment: My compiler (gcc 11) can't compile this code: `error: expected expression before 'signed'`. To make it compile, you can do : `v &= -(signed)(v);`.  Btw attribution would be nice:  this has been developed by Sean Eron Anderson.

Comment: This is copied from this website: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel

Answer (score 8):

On GCC on X86 platform you can use `__builtin_ctz(no)`
On Microsoft compilers for X86 you can use `_BitScanForward`

They both emit a bsf instruction

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (I'm surprised it's not mentioned here) would be to build a table of 256 integers, where each element in the array is the lowest 1 bit for that index.  Then, for each byte in the integer, you look up in the table.

Something like this (I haven't taken any time to tweak this, this is just to roughly illustrate the idea):

```
int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
   static const unsigned char table[256] = { /* TODO: populate with constants */ };

   for (int i=0; i<sizeof(x); ++i, x >>= 8)
   {
      unsigned char r = table[x & 0xff];

      if (r)
         return r + i*8;    // Found a 1...
   }

   // All zeroes...
   return sizeof(x)*8;
}
```

The idea with some of the table-driven approaches to a problem like this is that `if` statements cost you something in terms of branch prediction, so you should aim to reduce them.  It also reduces the number of bit shifts.  Your approach does an `if` statement and a shift per bit, and this one does one per byte.  (Hopefully the optimizer can unroll the for loop, and not issue a compare/jump for that.)  Some of the other answers have even fewer `if` statements than this, but a table approach is simple and easy to understand.  Of course you should be guided by actual measurements to see if any of this matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
int countTrailZero(unsigned x) {
    if (x == 0) return DEFAULT_VALUE_YOU_NEED;
    return log2 (x & -x);  
}
```

Explanation:

x & -x returns the number of right most bit set with 1.

e.g. 6 -> "0000,0110", (6 & -6) -> "0000,0010"

You can deduct this by two complement:
x = "a1b", where b represents all trailing zeros.
then

```
-x = !(x) + 1 = !(a1b) + 1 = (!a)0(!b) + 1 = (!a)0(1...1) + 1 = (!a)1(0...0) = (!a)1b
```

so

`x & (-x) = (a1b) & (!a)1b = (0...0)1(0...0)`

you can get the number of trailing zeros just by doing log2.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
int bitcount(unsigned char x)
{
  int b;
  for(b=0; b<7; x>>=1)
  {
    if(x&1)
      break;
    else
      b++;
  }
  return b;
}
```

or even

```
int bitcount(unsigned char x)
{
  int b;
  for(b=0; b<7 && !(x&1); x>>=1) b++;
  return b;
}
```

or even (yay!)

```
int bitcount(unsigned char x)
{
  int b;
  for(b=0; b<7 && !(x&1); b++) x>>=1;
  return b;
}
```

or ...

Ah, whatever, [there are 100500 millions methods of doing this](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/). Use whatever you need or like.

Comment: Link provided just for a reference, and it's for bit counting. But you got the idea.

Comment: What's the usage of `x>>1` in these codes when they don't save?

Comment: Well, it's weird to hear this question from someone trying to implement such a task. It's called a bit shift: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html

Comment: "Shifting Doesn't Change Values", said in your mentioned link. `x>>1;` without saving the result in a variable. It's like writing `i+1;` !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is working (allthough you might want to use `unsigned int`). You check the last digit each time, and if it's zero, you discard it an increment the number of trailing zero-bits.

I think for trailing zeroes you don't need a loop.

Consider the following:

- What happens with the number (in binary representation, of course) if you subtract 1? Which digits change, which stay the same?
- How could you combine the original number and the decremented version such that only bits representing trailing zeroes are left?

If you apply the above steps correctly, you can just find the highest bit set in O(lg n) steps (look [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog) if you're interested in how to do).

Answer (score 0):

We can easily get it using bit operations, we don't need to go through all the bits. Pseudo code:

```
int bitcount(unsigned x) {
    int xor = x ^ (x-1); // this will have (1 + #trailing 0s) trailing 1s
    return log(i & xor); // i & xor will have only one bit 1 and its log should give the exact number of zeroes
}
```

Comment: What is the `i`?