# Efficient code to count the number of trailing 0s at the end of a binary number

Tags: python, string, list

I was looking into a method for finding the number of trailing zeros in binary numbers and came across a solution in C ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812044/finding-trailing-0s-in-a-binary-number)). I am looking for a solution in Python!

```
Binary Input -> 1000
Output: 3

Binary Input -> 101101001100
Output: 2

Binary Input -> 1010001010000
Output: 4

Binary Input -> 100000001
Output: 0
```

**Is there an efficient way of doing this without iterating the binary number as a string or using string methods for filtering**? Basically, I may have a very large number of very very large binary numbers, so I am trying to find something more efficient than simply iterating over it as a string.

---

EDIT:

Here is my attempt -

```
def trailingzeros(l):
    count = 0
    a = [i for i in str(l)]
    for i in reversed(a):
        if i=='0':
            count+=1
        else:
            break
    return count
```

NOTE: I am looking for a solution that exploits the binary nature of the input.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am looking for a solution in python and not in C as answered by this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812044/finding-trailing-0s-in-a-binary-number

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 0b1010001010000

count = 0
while n:
    if (n&1):
        break
    n >>= 1
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Comment: This solutions uses binary and (`n & 1`) and shift (`n >>=1`) which are as optimized as you can get with Python. +1

Comment: Thanks this works. i was looking for binary operations to exploit instead of string operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python bit operators:

```py
def findTrailing0(num):
    count = 0
    lastBit = 0
    while num != 0:
        lastBit = num & 0x1
        if lastBit != 0:
            break
        count += 1
        num >>= 1
    return count
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, is there any logical difference between this and the previous answer by @andrej.

Comment: No. It is basically the same solution.